# Why is my self-signed wildcard certificate not working?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

I have successfully created and used a self-signed certificate on my development machine (IIS 7.5  - Windows 7).

To do this I generated a self signed cert with a common name (CN) = `app.localhost` and imported it into the *Trusted Root Certification Authorities* store. I then imported the same cert into IIS and bound it to my site with a Host Name = `app.localhost`.

This worked fine.

Now I am developing an api that runs under `api.localhost`. This too needs SSL. So I created a new self-signed cert as before except I specifed a CN = `*.localhost`. The new cert was added to the *Trusted Root Certification Authorities* store and imported into IIS as before. Both sites (`app.localhost` & `api.localhost`) were successfully bound to the wildcard cert.

This did not work.

Chrome complains with:

> You attempted to reach api.localhost, but instead you actually reached
>   a server identifying itself as *.localhost.

IE makes a similar complaint.

How do I make a self-signed wildcard certificate that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by David Schwartz this doesn't work for Top Level domains. However it works for any domain below that.

To my c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file I added

```
127.0.0.1 mysitename.localhost.dev
```

Here .dev is the top level, so I can issue a wildcard to *.localhost.dev

I haven't done this with IIS but this works fine using apache and specifying

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/hookd/mysite/public
    ServerName mysitename.localhost.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Unfortunately you'll have to setup a new entry in `hosts` and in the apache config for each site but it's a lot easier than signing a new certificate.

Answer (score 3):

Wildcard certificate for top-level domains aren't allowed by typical browsers for reasons that should be quite obvious if you think about it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Can you provide any details how I would go about creating the type of wildcard certificate I need?

Comment: Use something like `*.myapp.dev`